# Showing that M is a finitely generated R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Lemma: Let $A$ be an $R$-Algebra such that $A$ is a finitely generated  $R$-Module. Let $M$ be a finitely generated $A$-module. Show that $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-Module.

Proof:

So things I know is that for any $a\in A$: $a=a_1r_1+...+a_nr_n$ with $a_i \in A$ and $r_i \in R$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$

For $m\in M$, it'd be $m=m_1b_1+...+m_tb_t$ with $m_j\in M$ and $b_j\in A$  and $t\in\mathbb{N}$.
How can I get the connection in order to show this lemma.

Comment: That’s bad notation. You have some *specific* finite set of $a_i$ that generate $A$ over $R$; if you call them $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ (and then the index of the $r$ should be $n$, not $k$), then you shouldn’t use the same names for the elements of $M$. Rather, there are $m_1,\ldots,m_t$ in $M$ such that every $m\in M$ can be written as $m_1b_1+\cdots + m_tb_t$, with $b_j\in A$. Now, each $b_j$ can be written in terms of $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, so....

Comment: What happens after you rewrite each of the $b_j$ in terms of the $a_i$?